Facing issue while creating azure student account
I am trying to activate azure student account with my college e-mail id but during academic verification it is showing:
"Your email domain is not currently registered with us. You can choose another verification method.".
Please help to resolve this.
I also tried to do this with github account but facing the same problem.

For your error it means your school's domain has not been verified for academic eligibility. You can check the status of your school's academic eligibility by going to the Microsoft 365 admin center and looking at the Billing card. If your school's eligibility is pending, it can take up to 10 business days to complete the manual eligibility review. If your school is not eligible, you can try using a personal email address to create a Microsoft account or link an existing Microsoft account.

Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/subscriptions/verify-academic-eligibility?view=o365-worldwide#verify-your-schools-academic-eligibility
